# How to hide times on calendar events in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, calendar, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to hide the time that appears on each event on my calendar in SharePoint 2013.  All I want to show on the events in month view is the title.  I might add that the events showing up on the calendar are from different overlay calendars.  For instance, in my list I have an employee start date.  So when I create a new employee item in my list and give he/she a start date then I just want the Employees' name on the calendar highlighted. However when I create a new employee it shows up as:

12:00 - 12:00 
[Emloyee Name]

Does anyone know how to resolve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways that i am aware of.

1. make all your Event content types childs of the builtin "Event" content type,  and then tick the box that says "Is this an All day event?"
2. do a bit of a JS hack, and remove it on load.

I would Strongly suggested using number 1.